# Error on CAS redirect when ticket is SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, cas

One client application in Spring Boot (Spring Security + Tomcat) try to authenticate against CAS (Central aunthencation Service) that runs in JBoss 7.1, after detect that user is not authenticated, application is redirected to CAS login page, so their credentials are inserted and is generated a GRANT_SERVICE_TICKET from CAS. So after it, CAS sends a redirect link to Spring Boot application client including the token, but unexpectedly something happens and multiples redirects are sent to browser showing the message: "The page isn't redirecting properly".

CAS receives and generates the ticket, but Spring Boot can not confirm that ticket was accepted. As described in log bellow:

```
=============================================================
17:45:53,009 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-9022-1) WHO: user123
17:45:53,009 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-9022-1) WHAT: ST-87-TCHz2sQeio0bR5gB2TZt-localhost for https://localhost:9043/useraccess/login/cas
17:45:53,009 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-9022-1) ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
17:45:53,009 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-9022-1) APPLICATION: CAS
17:45:53,024 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-9022-1) WHEN: Fri Jun 05 17:45:53 BRT 2015
17:45:53,024 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-9022-1) CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
17:45:53,024 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-9022-1) SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
17:45:53,024 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-9022-1) =============================================================
```

My CAS server runs in JBoss 7.1 server at https://localhost:9022/cas
My Spring Boot runs at https://localhost:9043/useraccess/

Does anybody have any idea? It seems Spring Boot can not handle cross redirects between different servers. At the moment, my CAS authentication works in web applications, and I am trying to convert to Spring Boot one.

Thanks!

Comment: Much times this happens with me. But always were problems with parameters. Do you have certain that url that CAS is redirecting your JBOSS is correct ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.. I used a sniffer to verify http requests and it´s the same parameters... My guess is there something I need to set in Spring Boot to allow redirect across different servers or receive something from there.

Comment: Are you sure that are the correct port. I don't use spring boot, but did you configure the certificates too ?

Comment: I used the same certificate in both servers, I even tried out CAS and Spring without certificates to eliminate SSL questions and the same error has happened, so the only difference are servers and ports different for each one.

Comment: When the CAS redirect your app, it redirect to correct port ? You can show for me the URL that your CAS Server create. FYI: CAS not works without SSL

Comment: Well I tried my client application in JBoss and there worked fine without SSL, there´s an option in CAS that you say if it´s possible to accept non-SSL requets. But let´s go back to question, if you look at CAS ticket created that I inserted at top, you see CAS trying to redirect to  https://localhost:9043/useraccess/login/cas (Spring Boot)

Comment: Great! For me CAS Server works only with SSL enabled. Sorry. Come back to the main issue. Seems that you really have a problem with your redirect. Can you post your CAS client configuration like your bean serviceProperties and casAuthenticationEntryPoint

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my current CAS configuration, as WAR application in JBoss 7.1 it works fine, but when is used in Spring Boot something does not work, it seems can not receive the ticket granted from CAS when redirects to application home.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CasConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WebAppProperty webAppProperty; 

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Main configurations
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

        // Authorize sub-folders permissions
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*").authenticated();

        http.addFilter(logoutFilter());
        http.addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter());

        final ServiceProperties serviceProperties = serviceProperties();
        http.authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider(serviceProperties));
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(casProcessingFilterEntryPoint(serviceProperties));
    }

    private CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casProcessingFilterEntryPoint(final ServiceProperties serviceProperties)
            throws IOException {
        final String casLoginUrl = securityProperty().getCASLoginURL();
        final CasAuthenticationEntryPoint casAuthenticationEntryPoint = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setLoginUrl(casLoginUrl);
        casAuthenticationEntryPoint.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties);

        return casAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    private CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final String webappLocation = webAppProperty.getContextLocation();
        final SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(webappLocation);

        final String casLogoutUrl = securityProperty().getCASLogoutURL();
        final SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler(
                casLogoutUrl);

        final CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(simpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler);
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(savedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        casAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(super.authenticationManagerBean());

        return casAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    private LogoutFilter logoutFilter() throws IOException {
        final String logoutURL = securityProperty().getCASLogoutURL();
        final LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter(logoutURL, new SecurityContextLogoutHandler());

        return logoutFilter;
    }

    private CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider(final ServiceProperties serviceProperties)
            throws IOException, NamingException {
        final String casServerLocationSSL = securityProperty().getCASServer();
        final Cas20ServiceTicketValidator ticketValidator = new Cas20ServiceTicketValidator(casServerLocationSSL);

        final CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
        casAuthenticationProvider
                .setAuthenticationUserDetailsService(new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<CasAssertionAuthenticationToken>(
                        userDetailsService()));
        casAuthenticationProvider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        casAuthenticationProvider.setTicketValidator(ticketValidator);
        casAuthenticationProvider.setKey("an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only");

        return casAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    private ServiceProperties serviceProperties() throws IOException {
        final String casServiceLocationSSL = securityProperty().getCASService();
        final ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService(casServiceLocationSSL);

        return serviceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityProperty securityProperty() {
        return new SecurityPropertyImpl();
    }
}
```